# ASP.NET cookie value null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies

I have cookie that I create in a Login page and the read in the Home page

Login:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Login");
cookie.Values["User"] = textBox.Text;
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
cookie.Path = Request.ApplicationPath;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Home:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Login"];
string user = cookie.Values["User"];
```

When the Home page loads, I get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (pointing at the second line of the Home page)

I have this application running in 5 different servers and this is the only one that shows me an error when trying to read the cookie.

Note: this happens on Google Chrome, Microsoft edge and Internet Explorer

Note 2: I checked and the cookie exists on Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

When generating a cookie, path is case sensitive if the path you set differs in case from what is typed, it will not be stored.

[Cookie Path explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695736/formsauthentication-setauthcookie-not-setting-path-or-domain)

In this example path is set as "/".

```
Cookie.Values["User"] = textBox.Text;
Cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
Cookie.Secure = false;
Cookie.Path = "/";
Cookie.Domain = "DomainName";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(NewCookie);
```